# Select data using PDO and a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I try to select one nome from my bd it doesn't show anything

That's the function to select a name:

```
public function searchName(){
    $db = new Conection();
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dog WHERE id = 1");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        return $row['name'];//return to getName

    }
}
```

here is the code from getName:

```
    require 'Conection.php';
    require 'model/Dog.php';

    $dog = new Dog;
    $res = $dog->searchName(1);

    echo $res;
```

The class Connection is ok.

Comment: Since it is an object you need to `return $row->name;` And you do not need a loop here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` you should:

```
return $row->name;
```

And since you call:

```
$res = $dog->searchName(1);
```

Your function declaration must be:

```
public function searchName($id){
    $db = new Conection();
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dog WHERE id = ?");
    $query->bindParam(1,$id);
    $query->execute();
```

Comment: I am just asking to make sure.

Comment: :-) just checked with http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php  lokks ok. If any particular suggestion you are welcome

Comment: Maybe Jay prefer:

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dog WHERE id = :id");    

$query->bindParam(':id',$id);

Answer (score 0):

there is some problem in your code, 
you are not using function arguments after passing it
**and here are just want one row to return**
than you should use `$query->fetch` not `$query->fetchAll`

your code should be like this

```
public function searchName($id){
    $db = new Conection();
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dog WHERE id = :id");
    $query->execute(array('id'=>$id)); // bind parameters for security
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     // updated object with assoc... ie if obj used than return $result->name   
    return $result['name'];            
}
```

and than

```
echo $res = $dog->searchName(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is `$row['name']`
but
PDO::FETCH_OBJ is `$row->name`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php